# Extracting quotes between apostrophes in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, text, quotes

I'm working on a regex to capture the text in quotes. It works, however the plain text which is the source file, has converted single smart quotes to apostrophes.

For the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/QNqSsp/1) I have:

```
r("[\"|\'|\`].+[\"|\'|\`]")
```

The regex works fine but also grabs text between two apostrophes as well. Is is possible to adjust the regex so it doesn't do this?

```
"Come up and see me some time" # correct
'Yeah, I wonder if will pick this up to' #correct
`Mmmm. I wonder...` # correct
"Sorry about the mess!" #correct
We don't know who is human. Don't we? # Wrong.
```

The last one grabs

```
't know who is human. Don'
```

Comment: Try to use (non-)word boundaries. E.g., try ``\B["'`].+?["'`]\B``

Comment: Put in escape slashes for quotes and that's an answer, thanks :)

Comment: You do not need to escape them, just use `r"""pattern_here"""`.

Comment: I got an error in regex101, telling me to escape them, that's all.

Comment: Just learn to use regex101 - https://regex101.com/r/TOLYVc/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend non-word boundaries (`\B`) like @Wiktor commented, but also use a backreference (`\1`) to match the same quote character as the starting quote character:

```
regex = r"\B([\"'`]).+?\1\B"
```

test it here https://regex101.com/r/TOLYVc/3